# How to use existing Container Registry when creating AKS cluster in Pulumi Azure Native

Tags: azure, pulumi

I created Azure Container Registry (ACR) and now need to create Managed Cluster (AKS). When we use Azure Portal or Azure CLI, we can integrate existing ACR. In Pulumi Azure Native, `ManagedClusterArgs` does not have any property to accept existing ACR.

**How to attach already created ACR when creating Managed Cluster**?

Or assigning `AcrPull` role to the automatically created User Assigned Managed Identity (`<clsuter-name>-agentpool`) will achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you need to assign `AcrPull` role to managed identity of the cluster (VMSS).

(*make sure that the Service Principal used by Pulumi CLI has `User Access Administrator` role, otherwise Pulumi would not be able to create role assignment*)

Here is an example using a system-assigned managed identity in **TypeScript**:

```ts
const cluster = new containerservice.ManagedCluster("managedCluster", {
    // ...
    identity: {
        type: "SystemAssigned",
    },
});

const creds = containerservice.listManagedClusterUserCredentialsOutput({
    resourceGroupName: resourceGroup.name,
    resourceName: cluster.name,
});

const principalId = cluster.identityProfile.apply(p => p!["kubeletidentity"].objectId!);

// const registry = ...
// const subscriptionId = ...

const roleDefinitionId = `/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d`;
const assignment = new azure_native.authorization.RoleAssignment("acr-pull", {
    properties: {
        principalId: principalId,
        roleDefinitionId: roleDefinitionId,
    },
    scope: registry.id,
});
```

**C#**:

```cs
// var mainAcr = new AzureNative.ContainerRegistry.Registry("MainContainerRegistry", new AzureNative.ContainerRegistry.RegistryArgs { // ... });
// var aksAppCluster = new ManagedCluster("AksAppplicationCluster", new ManagedClusterArgs { // ... });

var vmssManagedIdentityPrincipalId = aksAppCluster.IdentityProfile.Apply(identityProfile =>
{
    var vmssManagedIdentityProfile = identityProfile!["kubeletidentity"];
    return vmssManagedIdentityProfile.ObjectId;
});

var acrPullRoleDefinitionId = RoleUtil.GetAcrPullRoleDefinitionId();
// I created RoleUtil and GetAcrPullRoleDefinitionId() will return: "subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/7f951dda-4ed3-4680-a7ca-43fe172d538d"
    
var roleAssignment = new AzureNative.Authorization.RoleAssignment(AcrPullRoleAssignment, new AzureNative.Authorization.RoleAssignmentArgs
{
    PrincipalId = vmssManagedIdentityPrincipalId!,
    PrincipalType = AzureNative.Authorization.PrincipalType.ServicePrincipal,
    RoleDefinitionId = acrPullRoleDefinitionId,
    Scope = mainAcr.Id,
});
```

For built-in role ids: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles

Comment: How to get `cluster.principalId` in C#? and is this `cluster.principalId` same as managed identity used Master Plane (API Server)? when we use Azure Portal, `<clsuter-name>-agentpool` (user assigned managed identity) gets the `AcrPull` role

Comment: Good question - I expanded my example to highlight the managed identity part